# How can I change heading color in Bootstrap dark mode?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, darkmode

The Bootstrap documentation shows how to [enable dark mode](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#enable-dark-mode):

```html
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, this displays titles in a darker white than the dark mode in the Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#dark-mode):

> **Color modes**
>
> Bootstrap now supports color modes, or themes, as of v5.3.0. Explore our default light color mode and the new dark mode, or create your own using our styles as your template.

How can I enable the same color scheme as Bootstrap's documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element on the docs page you'll see this, from the custom stylesheet for that site:

```css
.bd-content>h2,.bd-content>h3,.bd-content>h4 {
  --bs-heading-color: var(--bs-emphasis-color)
}
```

If you then click on the `--bs-emphasis-color` custom property you see that it's set in _root.scss:

```css
--bs-emphasis-color: #fff;
```

You can similarly override custom properties in your custom stylesheet. Here I'm using a class on the body element to provide adequate selector specificity. I'm also leveraging the existing emphasis color property variable to keep things dynamic (theoretically more maintainable).

```css
[data-bs-theme=dark] .brighter {
  --bs-heading-color: var(--bs-emphasis-color);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="brighter">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

More on customization: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/overview/#overview